# Different results with identical filter code

Tags: r, dplyr

I am running some dplyr functions on [hflights](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hflights/versions/0.1/topics/hflights).

I'd like to know how many weekend flights flew a distance of more than 1000 miles but had a total taxiing time below 15 minutes?

I think the two sets of code below should generate identical results - can someone tell me why they are different ?

```
filter(hflights,DayOfWeek==6|DayOfWeek==7 & Distance >1000 & TaxiIn+TaxiOut <15)
A tibble: 2,841 x 21
```

```
filter(hflights,DayOfWeek %in% c(6,7) & Distance >1000 & TaxiIn+TaxiOut <15)
A tibble: 155 x 21
```

Comment: for precedence in evaluating the filter arguments, use parentheses (e.g., (DayOfWeek==6 | DayOfWeek==7)) - then should give you the same results

Answer (score 1):

Without using parentheses, the or operator in your example `|` essentially compares everything to the left of the `|` operator to everything to the right of it.   Therefore, the first expression `DayOfWeek==6|DayOfWeek==7 & Distance >1000 & TaxiIn+TaxiOut <15`
 produces an output of everything that is either:

1. `DayOfWeek==6`

   - or
2. `DayOfWeek==7 & Distance >1000 & TaxiIn+TaxiOut <15`

When using the `%in%` operator, you are essentially using the `|` operator *with* parentheses:

- `DayOfWeek %in% c(6,7)` is the same as `(DayOfWeek==6 | DayOfWeek==7)`

Therefore, the second expression `DayOfWeek %in% c(6,7) & Distance >1000 & TaxiIn+TaxiOut <15` produces an output of everything that is either:

1. `DayOfWeek==6 & Distance >1000 & TaxiIn+TaxiOut <15`

   - or
2. `DayOfWeek==7 & Distance >1000 & TaxiIn+TaxiOut <15`

The first expression could be modified with parentheses as `filter(hflights,(DayOfWeek==6 | DayOfWeek==7) & Distance >1000 & TaxiIn+TaxiOut <15)` to produce the same results as if using the second expression.